# How can I put a title on my ArrayAdapter using a String field from an object?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

This is my arrayAdapter:

```
List<Nota> notas;
notas = bd.buscar(); // this function returns a list of Objects "Nota"

ArrayAdapter<Nota> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Nota>
(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, notas);

list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

The object Nota has 2 fields, an Integer, and a String. 
I want to put the String field from Nota as title of the ArrayAdapter, how can I do that?

Comment: Then what problem you are getting ?

Comment: ArrayAdapter is using [`Object.toString()`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#L409) override it ... or override getView of ArrayAdapter

Comment: Thanks. I overrode getView() and it works.